# Prove that projection is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I prove it?

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $$f(x,y)=y$$where $x=(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $y=(y_{1},y_{2},\ldots,y_{m})\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.
> Prove that $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ and find $f'(x,y), \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, only using definition.

**My attempt:** We need to use the definition and prove that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b):(x,y)-\{(a,b)\}}\frac{||f(x,y)-(f(a,b)+L((x,y)-(a,b))||}{||(x,y)-(a,b)||}=0$$
Using the hint of @Benjamin, we have that let $L: \mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $L(x,y)=(0,y)$. So, wew have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{|| (0,y)-((0,b)+L((a-b,y-b)) ||}{||(x,y)-(a,b)||}&=&\frac{||(0,y)-((0,b)+(0,y-b))||}{||(x,y)-(a,b)||}\\
&=&\frac{||(0,0)||}{||(x,y)-(a,b)||}=0
\end{eqnarray*}
So, $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b):(x,y)-\{(a,b)\}}\frac{||f(x,y)-(f(a,b)+L((x,y)-(a,b))||}{||(x,y)-(a,b)||}=0$$
Is it correct?
*But, $f(x,y)=y$ is the same that $f(x,y)=(0,y)$?*

Comment: If you choose $L$ correctly you will in fact have $$f(x,y) - f(a,b) - L((x,y) - (a,b)) = 0.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is a linear function you can choose $L(x,y)=f(x,y)=y$ and you are done.

Or if you like matrix representation of linear maps better: $ L =\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\end{pmatrix}. $

Comment: A question, $L(x,y)=y$ or $L(x,y)=(0,y)$? note that $f(x,y)=y$ by hypothesis.

Comment: You are right, $L$ should be a linear function $\mathbb R^{m+n}\to\mathbb R^m$ (just like $f$). I will correct my answer.